# Finding the points of an Image (PNG) to make a polygon

Tags: image, polygon

If I have an image (PNG) is there anyway to find the polygon representation of that image? I am using Cocos2d and SpaceManager to build an iPhone application. There are many images that are polygon in shape. I need to give those images the characteristics of a polygon.

Language => Objective C

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. Please edit the question.

Comment: I need to know which programming language your are planning to find the points in.

Comment: Maybe an example of a PNG with the mentioned points in it?

Comment: I wrote a tracer software some time ago. Basically, it "traced" the image outline/corners into positions. However, it didn't work with empty space inside the image (which was fine for my use-case).